# How to Logout user with Basic auth?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I can log in, perfectly fine, but can't get logout to give me a JSON response. Currently, I can only do POST to

```
d8.com/user/logout?csrf_token=123&?_format=json
```

and that would log out, even though the token 123 is not the same as the given csrf-token at login or the logout token. This doesn't work without the token query, even though cookie/session isn't enabled anywhere

> ("message": "'csrf_token' URL query argument is missing.").

The logout happens when hitting a 403 forbidden on that URL.

Other info:
csrf_token=123 is the actual query, doesn't need to be csrf-token or the log out token is given at login
Version: 8.5.3
The only basic_auth turned ON, at all endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in the url parameters, it should be :

```
d8.com/user/logout?token=123
```

The *_format* is not needed for logout.
I found the parameter name for the token on this page https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Access%21CsrfAccessCheck.php/function/CsrfAccessCheck%3A%3Aaccess/8.3.x